# How to manipulate the appearance of HTML Custom Validation via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

How is it possible to customize the style of validation feedback of JavaScript or use the speechbubbelish?

I'll show two examples:

[image: Validation 1]

[image: Validation 2]

I'd like to have the validation displayed on the second screenshot similar to the first one (and not only appearing on mousover). 
What led me to the feedback on the second screenshot:

```
<input id="MyInputField" type=text required></input>

function setCustomVal() {
    let field = document.getElementById("MyInputField");
    field.setCustomValidity("User Feedback");
}
```

this is not exactly the code i took the screenshot from, but it was achieved in the same manner.

i'd like to give a custom user feedback on validation like on the first picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be more ideal to use third party library called [popper.js](https://popper.js.org/), they provide good documentation on styling of pop ups/hints. Though, you need to apply new validation methods manually instead of using required attribute.

```js
var popper = new Popper(referenceElement, onPopper, {
    placement: 'bottom'
});
```

Comment: thanks, i think i could achieve a decent validation feedback with the proposed library popper.js. Nevertheless i'd prefer using a built in solution to minimize dependencies. Obviously it is somehow built in HTML5, but i cannot trigger it via JavaScript, is that correct?

Comment: For the moment yes, you cannot trigger it manually using javascript unless the input field has a required field and the input field is empty that is why many libraries such as popper is created to solve that issue